# Partitioned Queues with Service Bus Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

Has anyone had any experience with Service Bus partitioned queues with Azure Functions?

Im struggling to find any examples for how to use them and also how to enforce that partitions can be processed in parallel but each partition can only have 1 message processed at a time

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive from a partition. You receive from a queue/subscription. If you need to receive from the same queue/subscription by some identifier, [message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) is what you should look into. Message sessions will give you parallel processing and concurrency you want.

Comment: Ok thanks I did find this earlier https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency the section Session based single dispatch topic/queue processing is relevant I think?

Comment: Indeed. You can have multiple concurrent sessions processed. Or just one. And per session, you could do one message at a time.